# Can't connect to Oracle server from my machine using Microsoft's SSMA for Oracle tool

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008-r2, database-migration

I'm trying to connect to Oracle 9i database from my machine (Windows 7 x64) using Microsoft's tool *SSMA for Oracle v7.6.0* but getting the following error :

```
System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.
```

A quick search on the Internet shows that this error message is quite generic accross Microsoft products which can connect to Oracle databases. I have no idea which Oracle software should I install, and how to configure SSMA so as to be able to use it.

How can I solve this issue ?